# How to check that all hibernate queries for a table have a condition for a specific column?

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a deleted column on our table, is it possible to check that every time this table is queried the query has a condition for this column?

Some googling with better keywords (soft-delete) it seems I could do this with @When annotation. not exactly what I was looking but seems close enough.

Comment: Kindly post your code what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `@Where` annotation.

[org.hibernate.annotations.Where](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.java)

Example:
If there's an Account Entity

```java
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Where( clause = "active = true" )
public static class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    @Column(name = "account_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountType type;

    private Double amount;

    private Double rate;

    private boolean active;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

}
```

and if the following code is used for fetching the accounts.

```java
List<Account> accounts = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select a from Account a", Account.class)
    .getResultList();
```

then the following SQL will be generated

```sql
SELECT
    a.id as id1_0_,
    a.active as active2_0_,
    a.amount as amount3_0_,
    a.client_id as client_i6_0_,
    a.rate as rate4_0_,
    a.account_type as account_5_0_
FROM
    Account a
WHERE ( a.active = true )
```

[Hibernate ORM 5.2.18.Final User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where)